# Is it possible to perform cascade delete without fluent configuration in onModelCreating?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Basically I have Model e.g

```
public class Dealer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; } = new List<Car>();
}

public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

I've been trying to do something like this:

```
var dealer = _context.Dealers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);

foreach (var car in dealers.Cars)
{
    _context.Cars.Remove(car);
    // _context.Entry(car).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}

dealer.Cars.Clear();

_context.Dealers.Remove(dealer);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Unfortunely it doesn't really work

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Cars_Dealer_DealerId". 
>   The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.Cars", column 'DealerId'.

Any ideas on how to perform delete with relations without fluent config?

> [CascadeDelete] attr.

Seems like it is not in EF Core

Comment: And why not fluent config? Fluent config is de facto standard in EF Core when default conventions do not apply. In your case, you have no explicit FK property in `Car`, so by convention the relationship is optional, hence no [cascade delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: You are making the assumption that Car is a child object of Dealer. That's not apparent in the question or the code. One has to guess by noting that all Cars are deleted before the Dealer. If *humans* have to guess, how is EF going to know Car is owned by Dealer? That's why you should configure that relation

Comment: BTW whether you configure the relation in EF or change the constraint to CASCADE DELETE you *have* to tell someone that Dealer owns Car instances

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ``how is EF going to know Car is owned by Dealer?`` He actually know, because he created db schema which handles it correctly (shadow FKEY) :P

Comment: @Joelty EF Core has no idea what is in you db schema. All it knows is your model and configuration. It's ORM, and correct M(apping) is your responsibility.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yea, you're right, but I meant that it's capable of creating schema correctly despite not having info about how to create relations

Comment: @Joelty that's not what that foreign key constraint says. That only says there's a constraint between tables. If that FK had a CASCADE DELETE setting, it would be closer to the "owns" relation. Besides, constraints are expressed as attributes or using the Fluent API. By *not* including that, you are hiding the information from EF

Comment: @Joelty Of course, it created FK, but *without* cascade delete, because as I wrote in my first comment, your model by convention does not imply cascade delete. So you need to tell EF Core to do that by using fluent API (override the conventional setting). I'm pretty sure if the convention was different, then someone would ask the opposite "can I turn cascade delete off w/o fluent config", and the answer will be the same - no,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is - no, it's not possible because this is the conventional behavior for this type of model ([Cascade Delete for optional relationhips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)), and when conventional behaviors do not work for you, you should override them with data annotations / fluent API. Since cascade delete behavior can be specified only with fluent API, you *must* use fluent configuration.

It would have been different if your relationship was [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships), e.g. `Car` having explicit *non nullable& FK `public Guid DealerId { get; set; }`, but then the question would be can you turn the cascade delete off, and the answer will be the same.

Shortly, use the fluent configuration, this is just one of the cases why data annotations / fluent API exist. The minimum is

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dealer>().HasMany(e => e.Cars).WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

And don't forget to generate new migration and update your database.